# A hard coding decoding problem

Tags: letters

If **LAZED** is coded as **Y1M2Q** then what is the code for ***STERILE***?

I can not see any patterns. Only thing that I observe is 'A' of L**A**ZED relating to '1' of Y**1**M2Q since 'A' is the '1'st letter of the alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be

> FG2E3Y2

Because

> You rot13, the consonants and you take the number value of the vowels where a=1 e=2 i=3 o=4 u=5

So,

> LAZED became L->y, A->1, Z->m, E->2, and D->q
> STERILE became S->f, T->g, E->2, R->e, I->3, L->y, and E->2